# fb:comments - how to moderate comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

I have a webpage on which I added a facebook comments plugin.

```
<fb:comments href="http://mywebsite.com" num_posts="20" width="510"></fb:comments>
```

How would I be able to moderate those comments? "mywebsite.com" is not actually the address where the page with the comments plugin is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to include the fb:admins and fb:app_id tag in the header of the site that is using the comments plugin:

```
  <head>
   ...
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID"/>
   <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
   ...
  </head>
```

Once you've done this you will see the moderate links on the comments box. You can also navigate to
      https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments
to see a list of all your apps that have comments plugins enabled.

More information here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: OK, this would work. But the comments plugin is inside a iframe that is being loaded into a facebook tab. So I cannot edit the meta property of the facebook page, only of the page being loaded via the iframe. Any solution to this?

Comment: Facebook reads the meta tags on the page that contains the comments plugin, the same page you specify in the href parameter when you set it up. Doesn't matter if it's in an iframe.